# Rails 5.2 uninitialized constant after code change, lib classes are not loaded after a code change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I set `config.cache_classes = false` in order for my code to reload after each change.

I am getting `uninitialized constant` after I do a simple change anywhere in code. Any class that should be in lib is not initialized or available. Code reloads just fine if I comment the needed constants.

I am getting the same result with `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false`

It's weird because the initial start work just fine.

This are the autoloaded paths

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Its somewhat unclear what you are doing here. By default Rails will not cache or eager load classes in development so you should not have to do any additional configuration besides adding the path to the autoload paths. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths-and-eager-load-paths

Comment: This is what I thought also... but it seems that I miss something.